# numpy.vdot for 2 vectors returns a matrix instead of a scalar?

Tags: numpy, matrix

```
v1=np.matrix([[-0.40824829],
 [-0.81649658],
 [-0.40824829]])
v2=np.matrix([[  8.94427191e-01],
 [ -4.47213595e-01],
 [  2.77555756e-16]])
np.vdot(v2, v1)
```

gives:

```
matrix([[-0.36514837]])
```

Why isn't it returning a scalar?

Comment: I see you're using `np.matrix`. This is one of the reasons not to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.einsum()` to get a scalar by either using as inputs `np.ndarray` or `np.matrix`:

```
np.einsum('ij, ij', v1, v2)
```

if `v1` and `v2` have the same `shape`.

Comment: sorry but I could never grasp einstein's summing convention :( how come that a simple dot product, which is defined as something returning a scalar requires such complexity?

Comment: @ihadanny I see your point... with arrays you could also do `(v1*v2).sum()`, I just wanted to give you a solution which is both fast and applicable also do `np.matrix`. In your caso, the scalar could easily be retrieved by extracting the first element of the resulting matrix with `result[0,0]`